# Galaxy Tab S can't boot into fastboot mode

Tags: fastboot, odin

I want to install a custom ROM on my Galaxy Tab S. Therefore, I need to install TWRP as recovery. For that, I need to unlock my bootloader. I'm following this guide to unlock my bootloader: http://rootmygalaxy.net/unlock-bootloader-android-using-fastboot-commands/

I installed the appropriate drivers and ADB&Fastboot on my computer. Then, I enabled debugging on my Galaxy Tab S. Then, I opened the command console and typed: "adb reboot bootloader". My tablet then restart, but doesn't go into fastboot mode. Instead, it simply reboot normally.

I've tried this on both, Mac OS and Windows. It does the same thing on both systems.

I've tried to boot while manually pressing Home, Power and Volume down buttons. Then, my Tab S into a special mode: Odin mode. I know I've used Odin previously to upgrade my Tab S from Lollipop to Marshmallow. I don't know if the fact that I hve Odin doesn't allow my tablet to boot into fastboot. However, I would need to boot into fastboot to unlock my bootloader and, later on, to install TWRP in order to installer the AOSP 7.0 Nougat custom ROM to my Galaxy Tab S.

How can I do to boot into fastboot mode?

Thank you very much,

Blaccko

Comment: Samsung disabled Fastboot on all their hardware. You must use Odin or Heimdall, instead.

Comment: But then, how do I unlock bootloader with Odin instead of fastboot? How I understand it is I need to unlock bootloader before installing TWRP and the custom ROM. Thanks

Comment: You said you previously upgraded to Marshmallow via Odin, didn't you? If you were able to do so, then your bootloader is already unlocked.

Comment: Good, thanks! In fact, I was able to install TWRP via Odin. Then, with TWRP, I installed the custom ROM AOSP 7.0 Nougat on my Tab S. Thanks! However, I realized that the UI of my Tab S (on 7.0) is different than the one of my S7 (also on 7.0). I was told this is because Samsung personalize the UI of 7.0. As I didn't get 7.0 on my tablet from Samsung, is there a way to manually install Samsung's UI for 7.0 on my tablet?
Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You must use

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```

Comment: Both `adb reboot bootloader` and `adb reboot-bootloader` does the same thing. Why do you suggest this? Did it explicitly work for your device? Which device is it?